# Double free error Stack pop Implementation

Tags: c, stack

```
typedef struct StackElement{    

    struct StackElement* below;    
    float value;

} sStackElement;

typedef struct StackElement* stack_top; 

float stack_pop(stack_top *stacktop)                                   
{
     sStackElement* temp = (sStackElement *) stacktop; 
     if(stacktop==NULL){
         return NAN;
     }    
     float temp2 = temp->value;                                
     stacktop = &(temp->below);                      

     free(temp);                                     

     return temp2;
}
```

I am trying to implement a stack pop function, but somehow I get a double free error.

In the function, I am creating a temporary pointer which points to the current stack:

- then I check if the pointer is Null.
- then I point top to the 2nd Element in the Stack.
- then I free temp (which points to the element on the top of the stack)
- then I get the double free error

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Isn't `temp->below` a pointer `sStackElement*` ? If so, you have an extra reference operator here `stacktop = &(temp->below);`

Comment: So you mean I should remove the "&" ? If I do that I get an Error which says that I am assigning an incompatible pointer type

Comment: So show us the definition of the `sStackElement` and `stack_top`

Comment: This doesn't solve your problem, but I would recommend structuring your code so there is only one return. Then use an If clause to handle the null case and an else to handle the non-null. Its always a little easier to follow when there is one exist point in a function.

Comment: The extra `&` is a problem, see my answer

Comment: this line: stacktop = &(temp->below); has the problem that 'below' is already a pointer to the rest of the stack, so using the '&' operator on the pointer yields a incorrect value.  suggest: stacktop = temp->below;  BTW: is the bottom 'below' contain a NULL, if not, then this code will fail during  a 'pop' operation because some trash will be returned rather than NULL.  Also, 'NAN' is not portable.

Comment: regarding this line: 'if(stacktop==NULL){'  if this is passed as '&(pMystack)', then it will never be NULL (and that is how it must be passed as this line: 'float stack_pop(stack_top *stacktop)' is actually this: 'float stack_pop(struct StackElement **stacktop)'  Note: obscuring the actual line, via all the typedef's is a very bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you're calling this as:

```
float value = stack_pop( &realstacktop );

// do more with stacktop
```

The problem is that this:

```
float stack_pop(stack_top *stacktop)                                   
{
   // ...
        stacktop = &(temp->below);                      
   // ...
}
```

does *nothing* to change the `realstacktop` you passed in. Call `stack_pop()` again, and you'll dereference - and free - the same top item.

You want to say:

```
*stacktop = temp->below;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `stack_top` is the same type as `temp->below` - they both are pointers to the `sStackElement`. So the line

```
stacktop = &(temp->below);
```

is actually assigning an `sStackElement **` to `sStackElement *`, which is not what is intended. So remove the reference operator `&`, and perform a cast if the compiler complains.

Comment: @Eugene Sh. Yeah, that's what I was trying to get out. I just typed it wrong the first time. -> is a dereferencing operation like using the "*" operator. So when you dereference a double pointer you get a pointer. But adding the & is rereferencing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
// called via: float value = stack_pop( &realstacktop );

#include <stdlib.h>
#define  NAN (0.0f) // only here for my compiler

struct StackElement
{
    struct StackElement* below;
    float value;
};



float stack_pop(struct StackElement **ppStacktop)
{
     if(*ppStacktop==NULL)
     { // then stack empty
         return NAN;
     }

     // implied else, stack not empty

        // save ptr to current stack top
     struct StackElement* temp = *ppStacktop;
        // retrieve value from current stack top
     float temp2 = temp->value;
        // pop current stack top entry
     *ppStacktop = temp->below;

     free(temp); // release 'old' stack top

     return temp2; // return retrieved value
} // end function: stack_pop
```